# javascript add elements to li tag

Tags: javascript, html

hi I want to add elements to LI when pressing on a link
I can add elements to a DIV like this

I have seen this question too [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0?rq=1)

## html code

```
<div id="div">
<a href="" onclick="add()">add</a>
</div>
```

## javascript code

```
function add(){

    var bigDiv = document.getElementById('div');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    bigDiv.appendChild(input);
    }
```

and it works good
but if I change the html code from div to li like this

## html code

```
<ul>
<li id="li">
<a href="" onclick="add()">add</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

## javascript

```
function add(){
var bigLi = document.getElementById('li');
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
bigLi.appendChild(input);
}
```

it doesn't work
I ensure that there is no syntax error

Comment: you are right , sorry , but i close it on my code already , i mean i make a mistake just in writing  the question but on my code i did it before i ask

Comment: when i use li and i press that link , i can see an input but remove fast , i mean it add input for a second and then the input disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your HTML:

- you have no closing `</a>`
- your onclick code isn't wrapped in `""` like `onclick="add()"`
- you didn't suppress the link's default action (which is to redirect). try [adding `href="#"`](http://jsfiddle.net/udJ8d/) to prevent it from moving away and [add `return false`](http://jsfiddle.net/udJ8d/1/) to the end of the function.

  ```
  <a href="#" onclick="add()">a</a>

  //AND

  function add(){
      ...
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Or you can prevent the default event on the link by returning false.

Comment: YES MAN THE WRONG WAS BECAUSE I DIDN'T ADD # TO MY HREF , THANK YOU

Comment: I WILL ACCEPT ANSWER AFTER 3 MINS  but i am wondering , how it works with div and not works with li :)

Comment: @Joseph When returning false from the function, the html should be changed to: `onclick="return add()"`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Writing with all caps is considered shouting on the web. Please don't do it.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know , any way the solution was to add # to my href , thank you all , and sorry bazmegakapa i didn't know what :)

Comment: **AND** add return false, not **OR**

Comment: @mplungjan actually, you can do either or both. using `href="#"` will not make the page go away (but add a hash in the url and jump the page) and return false prevents further action. both suppress page change. come to think about it, using both is a good idea.

Comment: @Joseph , yes but it is a problem , i don't want to add hash to the url , what should i do ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan then you should go for the `return false`

Comment: As I said Please go for BOTH - the return false is the most important and the # will stop the link from giving errors if JS is turned off. # alone will unload the page and go to top if you are further down